# Entire function with zeroes on real line

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let f be an entire function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ of order $1$ with zeroes only on real line. I need to prove that this function has following bound: $$\exists a>0\:\:\:|f(z)| \ge e^{-a|Im \:z|}|Re\:f(z)|$$ I have searched over some theorems about order and zeroes, found some approximation and factorisation theorems but not sure how they could help.

Comment: Is it $|\Im z|$ in the bound? I am not sure the result is correct otherwise as $|e^z|=e^x, |\Re e^z|=e^x |\cos y|$ and it is simply not true that if you fix an $a>0$ we have $1 \ge e^{-ay}|\cos y|$ for $y<0$ arbitrary as picking negative values of $y$ for which $\cos y=1$ shows

Comment: @Conrad Sorry, I have made a mistake, fixed it now.

Comment: Do you know about the Phragmen-Lindelof method?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I know only about PL for sector and a sector transformed into strip.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps Phragmen-Lindelof is not the right track here. Will have to think further.